# null after drop:javascript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, draggable, vanilla-forums

after i add  2-3 times and drop it in other place, on my item come null
here is my code .i can't understand where is my mistake
is there any mistake that i can fix...or maybe i forgot to add ...
can you pls say what is wrong ? its my first time use Drag&Drop so i'm a little bit confused

http://jsfiddle.net/adulik/8sqbcox2/15/

```
    function updateStyle() {

//get lise and list-item

  const list_items = document.querySelectorAll('.list-item');
  const lists = document.querySelectorAll('.list');

//circle fot list item and getting them

  let draggedItem = null;
  for (let i = 0; i < list_items.length; i++) {
    const item = list_items[i];

//start draggable items

    item.addEventListener('dragstart', function () {
      // console.log("dragstart")
      draggedItem = item;
      setTimeout(function () {
        item.style.display = 'none';
      }, 0);
    });

//finish draggable item

    item.addEventListener('dragend', function () {
      // console.log("dragend")
      setTimeout(function () {
        draggedItem.style.display = 'block';
        draggedItem = null;
      }, 0);
    });

//list of items

    for (let j = 0; j < lists.length; j++) {
      const list = lists[j];
      // console.log('list ', list);
      //take item and drag over (new element inside block )
      list.addEventListener('dragover', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      });

//enter the zone of draggable item

      list.addEventListener('dragenter', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)';
      });

//leave the zone and "delete" color

      list.addEventListener('dragleave', function (event) {
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';
      });

 //drop in the zone

      list.addEventListener('drop', function (event) {

//set  background color in drop zone

        this.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)';
        this.append(draggedItem);
      });
    }
  }
}

//creating the list

function createList(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

 //get title text

  const titleText = document.getElementById('titleText');
  console.log('titleText', titleText);

//if input is empty alert ....if not

  if (titleText.value.length === 0) {
    alert('dask cannot be empty, please add a title');
    return;
  }


//creating and append the element

  const lists = document.getElementById('lists');
  const list = createElement('div', '', 'list');
  const title = createElement('h3', titleText.value, 'list-title');
  const id = `task-${titleText.value}-list`;
  list.id = id;
  list.append(title);
  lists.append(list);
  const taskInput = createTaskInput(titleText.value);
  list.append(taskInput);
  titleText.value = '';
  updateStyle();
}

//create Element

function createElement(tag, text, className = null) {
  const element = document.createElement(tag);
  console.log('element', element);

 //if we have name then we add classList and return element

  if (className) {
    console.log('className', className);
    element.classList.add(className);
  }
  if (text && text.length > 0) {
    const textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
    element.appendChild(textNode);
  }
  return element;
}

//create new Task Input and append input and button

function createTaskInput(listName) {
  const form = createElement('form', '', 'task-form');
  const input = createElement('input', '');
  const button = createElement('button', '');
  const id = `task-${listName}`;
  input.name = 'task';
  input.id = id;
  button.innerText = 'Add';
  button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    addTaskListItem(id);
  });
  form.append(input);
  form.append(button);
  return form;
}

//add task list item

function addTaskListItem(id) {

  //get element by id

  const task = document.getElementById(id);

  //creating new task in block

  console.log('task ', task);
  if (task.value.length === 0) {
    alert('Cannot be empty');
    return;
  }
  const list = document.getElementById(`${id}-list`);
  const listItem = createElement('div', task.value, 'list-item');
  listItem.setAttribute('draggable', true);
  task.value = '';
  list.append(listItem);
  updateStyle();
}
```

*here you can explain me why so? *

Comment: In updateStyle you add event listeners to all the elements, including the ones which already have listeners.  That will cause weird behavior and could be the reason this is happening.  Only add listeners once to each element.  You might consider using delegated listeners so you only have to define them once on load.

Answer (score 1):

i found my mistake )) in setTimeout ...here in "dragend" i was adding

> draggedItem = null;

it was my mistake ))

```
//finish draggable item 

item.addEventListener('dragend', function () {
  // console.log("dragend")
  setTimeout(function () {
    draggedItem.style.display = 'block';
    draggedItem = null;
  }, 0);
});
```